# MySQL Restraint Not Being Passed Down Through Views

Tags: mysql, database, performance, view, where-clause

I am working with a system that has multiple views chained upon each other. For some reason, there is a problematic view which isn't passing the restraint down through the chain (despite them having a key in common). For example, here is the visual explain statement. [Visual Explain of SQL View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72w1F.png)

As you can see, the main view is based upon two other views (which, in turn, are based off another set of views). The problem view in this example is ResourcePointsAndCategories (on the right-hand side bottom). In this query, I am restraining results by a WHERE clause based on a column called HostID. HostID is in my supporting view; however, the key is not being passed down, and therefore, the view is loading 23,000 rows, instead of the 3 I want.

Any help to explain or correct this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, should have included the code from the start:

Here is for the main view:

```
VIEW `test`.`resourcepointswithlookupsandcategorycountandportalpagescount` AS
SELECT 
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`URL` AS `URL`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`Format` AS `Format`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`Host` AS `Host`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ResourceID` AS `ResourceID`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`HostID` AS `HostID`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`PermitID` AS `PermitID`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ResourceTitle` AS `ResourceTitle`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`FormatID` AS `FormatID`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`TypeID` AS `TypeID`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`Notes` AS `Notes`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`Description` AS `Description`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ReferenceFirstName` AS `ReferenceFirstName`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ReferenceLastName` AS `ReferenceLastName`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ReferenceEmail` AS `ReferenceEmail`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ReferencePermission` AS `ReferencePermission`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`ReferenceComment` AS `ReferenceComment`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`CreateDate` AS `CreateDate`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`CreateBy` AS `CreateBy`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LastEditDate` AS `LastEditDate`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LastEditBy` AS `LastEditBy`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LastReview` AS `LastReview`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LastReviewBy` AS `LastReviewBy`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`Type` AS `Type`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LibraryURL` AS `LibraryURL`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`TypeCollection` AS `TypeCollection`,
    `resourcepointsandcategoriescount`.`CategoryCount` AS `CategoryCount`,
    `portalpagecountwithresourcepointsandportaltitle`.`PortalPageCount` AS `PortalPageCount`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`NormFileStatus` AS `NormFileStatus`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`NormFileStatusDate` AS `NormFileStatusDate`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`FileSystemStatus` AS `FileSystemStatus`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`FileSystemStatusDate` AS `FileSystemStatusDate`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LanguageName` AS `LanguageName`,
    `resourcepointswithlookups`.`LanguageCode` AS `LanguageCode`
FROM
    ((`test`.`resourcepointswithlookups`
    LEFT JOIN `test`.`portalpagecountwithresourcepointsandportaltitle` ON ((`resourcepointswithlookups`.`ResourceID` = `portalpagecountwithresourcepointsandportaltitle`.`ResourcePointID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `test`.`resourcepointsandcategoriescount` ON ((`resourcepointswithlookups`.`ResourceID` = `resourcepointsandcategoriescount`.`ResourceID`)))
```

And here's the code for the problem view:

```
VIEW `test`.`resourcepointsandcategoriescount` AS
SELECT 
    `resourcepointsandcategories`.`ResourceID` AS `ResourceID`,
    `resourcepointsandcategories`.`HostID` AS `HostID`,
    COUNT(`resourcepointsandcategories`.`CategoryID`) AS `CategoryCount`
FROM
    `test`.`resourcepointsandcategories`
GROUP BY `resourcepointsandcategories`.`ResourceID`
```

And, ultimately, the view the problem view is based off of (which runs fine):

```
VIEW `test`.`resourcepointsandcategories` AS
SELECT 
    `test`.`resourcepoints`.`ResourceID` AS `ResourceID`,
    `test`.`resourcepoints`.`HostID` AS `HostID`,
    `test`.`lkupegcategories`.`Category` AS `Category`,
    `test`.`resourcepointcategories`.`CategoryID` AS `CategoryID`
FROM
    ((`test`.`resourcepointcategories`
    JOIN `test`.`resourcepoints` ON ((`test`.`resourcepointcategories`.`ResourceID` = `test`.`resourcepoints`.`ResourceID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `test`.`lkupegcategories` ON ((`test`.`lkupegcategories`.`eGCategoryID` = `test`.`resourcepointcategories`.`CategoryID`)))
```

The query I am calling is:

```
 SELECT * FROM test.resourcepointswithlookupsandcategorycountandportalpagescount WHERE HostID = 4532;
```

Comment: please show us some of your code so we can help properly

Comment: Added code! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

If I read your views correctly, you are filtering the first (big) view on `HostID = 4532`, but not filtering the other two views on it.

Perhaps the `ON` clauses need to include `AND res....HostID = res...HostID`.